# Smooth Animation on CAKeyframeAnimation for CATransform3D animations

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation, catransform3d

I've created my own transition animation between views.  I animate two properties, the position and the transform, to provide a cube-like transition between views. The frame uses `CABasicAnimation` while the transform uses a "2-stage" `CAKeyframeAnimation`. Everything works fine except for one small detail I can't seem to figure out.  In my transition I apply a `CATransform3DScale` on the middle key frame to create a zoom-in/zoom-out effect.  That works fine except the animation looks slightly jerky.  It's animating the between the key frames in a linear fashion, and I would like to smooth that out.  Now `CAKeyframeAnimation` has a way to do that using `calculationMode`, but it doesn't seem to work for transforms.  I've tried setting it to `kCAAnimationCubic` and `kCAAnimationCubicPaced` with no effect.

Here is the code that animates one view's transform (a similar block of code animates the other view):

```
    CAKeyframeAnimation *aTransform = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    CATransform3D transform1 = RotateOnX(toView, M_PI_4);
    transform1 = CATransform3DScale(transform1, RotationalZoom, RotationalZoom, RotationalZoom);
    [aTransform setValues:Array([NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:RotateOnX(toView, M_PI_2)],
                                [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform1],
                                [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:RotateOnX(toView, 0)])];
    [toView.layer addAnimation:aTransform forKey:@"transform"];
```

Note: `RotateOnX(UIView *, CGFloat)` is a block that returns a transform for a view rotated on X by the desired Radians.

As you can see I only set a scaling transform on the middle key frame.  Also, the rotation of the view is perfectly smooth, it's only the scaling that appears to 'jerk' as it changes direction.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to smooth out the scaling/zooming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `timingFunctions` property. Since you have 3 keyframes, you need 2 timing functions: one for the animation from keyframe 0 to keyframe 1, and another for the animation from keyframe 1 to keyframe 2.

```
aTransform.timingFunctions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInOut],
    [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInOut],
    nil];
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear...I was using a "frame" for a catch all of bounds, anchorPoint and position.  I do, in fact, only animate the position along with modified anchor points to 'move' my views.  I'll update my question to clarify.

Comment: Oh holy wow...I completely missed that and I looked over those class docs at least 10 times over 6 hours...ugh.  It works perfectly.  Seriously, thank you!

Comment: Oh, just FYI - It works better when you ease out and then ease in: `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut],
    [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn],
    nil];`